# nodejs throws TypeError: process.uptime is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to nodejs and I am using prom-client, getting the above error on using `process.uptime()`. I have tried adding several packages but no luck (the first three package was for similar other errors):

```
"cluster": "^0.7.7",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "repl": "^0.1.3",
    "node": "^12.2.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
```

and this is my other packages:

```
"@material-ui/core": "1.2.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "1.1.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^2.3.0",
    "react-number-format": "v3.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "express": "4.15.3",
    "prom-client": "^11.3.0"
```

Am I missing some basic library which can give all those functions? I can see this method here at https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime

I am getting the error message on the browser but not in the log:

```
TypeError: process.uptime is not a function
(anonymous function)
node_modules/prom-client/lib/metrics/processStartTime.js:4
  1 | 'use strict';
  2 | 
  3 | const Gauge = require('../gauge');
> 4 | const nowInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000 - process.uptime());
  5 | 
  6 | const PROCESS_START_TIME = 'process_start_time_seconds';
  7 | 
View compiled
./node_modules/prom-client/lib/metrics/processStartTime.js
```

Comment: Add the complete error stack trace

Comment: `node -e "console.log(process.uptime())"` works just fine.

Comment: @RolandStarke I too getting it working in the terminal, but not in my node js project.

Comment: Using your node version. Can you clone the prom-client `https://github.com/siimon/prom-client.git`, performs an `npm i` and then run the `npm test`.

Also try to run `node -e "console.log(process.uptime())"` to see if it works on your node.

Also what version of `prom-client` do you use ? Do a `npm list | grep prom-client`

Comment: @Akshaybarahate I have added more details in the question.

Comment: Hi @GrégoryNEUT, I cloned and did npm test, and it passed successfully. I run process.uptime() in console, and it worked fine. npm list returns prom-client@11.3.0

Comment: So It's certain it's about how you use it in your project. Is your project using webpack  ? using babel? What's your app for (front use/back use)?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I have added my full list of dependency in the question but I can see a webpack library in my node_modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are creating a *react.js* application and not a *node.js* server application.

*react* is front side when *node.js* is server side.

There is no `process.uptime()` because there is no *node.js* server involved.

[prometheus.io](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) library doesn't provide a client for *react*.